# Not able to git add

Tags: git, magento, ssh, amazon-ec2

I am new to this. When I try adding my magento development site hosted in AWS EC2 to git using `git add .`, I get the following error

```
error: open("var/cache/mage--0/mage---e84_DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_core_config_data_1"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file var/cache/mage--0/mage---e84_DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_core_config_data_1
fatal: adding files failed
```

I don't know if the file permission is the problem? I even tried changing the file permission to 777 using

```
sudo chmod 777 dir/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not attempt to add the whole magento folder to git, there are many folders that do not have anything to do with code. There are many solutions and ways of using git, but the most popular two are:

1. Only check in code that you have written / overridden. You have to create a big `.gitignore` file which states these ignores, there are many examples on the net.
2. Check in all the code but add the folders with images, caches etc into a .gitignore.

Git should not really be used for deployment.

Google is your friend:
https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/our-magento-git-guide-and-work-flow/

Comment: Thanks for the answer though I had already done this process :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in magento, all the files in var/ folder are owned by `www-data` webserver group only. You can check for the owner using `ls -la var/cache`

These include `var/log`, `var/cache` and `var/session`.
Ideally, you should not be adding any of these to your git repo, and your `var/` directory should be part of `.gitignore`.

My guess is, you are running the command `git add .` from your user, and your user is not part of the `www-data` group.
Thus, git can not traverse down the directory structure of `var/` because they are owned by a different group, and hence it is throwing up the error `Permission Denied`.